# After taking a break from university, which word fills "I will [word here] university", meaning that I'll go back to university

Tags: word-request

Basically, I took a break from university for 6 months.

How can I say that I am going "back" to university when I return to my country?

I was thinking about:

> "I am going to carry on with my university when I get back to my country."

or

> "I am going to resume my university when I get back to my country."

Hope you'll understand what I'm looking for!

Thank you!

Comment: You mean to say *when I get back to my country*? Because *by the time that...* means that you will have returned to university **before** you're back in the country.

Comment: In terms of American English, I think the question is already awkward, as it refers to 'university' as if it's some sort of activity. We don't take breaks from or return to 'university'. We take breaks from 'classes' or 'school' or "attending my university" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you actually un-enrolled (officially withdrew from the school), you could say that you will *re-enroll.*

> I took a break from university for 6 months to travel.  I will re-enroll when I get back to my country.

If not (say you were on a leave of absence or sabbatical), you could say

> I took a break from university for 6 months to travel.  I will start back up again when I get back to my country.

or

> I took a break from university for 6 months to travel.  I will go back to school when I get back to my country.

Or, slightly more formally,

> I took a break from university for 6 months to travel.  I will resume my studies when I get back to my country.

This second suggestion is very similar to one of your ideas about how to express it.  We don't usually talk about university as something one *does,* though.  It is a place we *attend,* or *go to*, or it modifies some other noun.  So your other suggestion could be modified to:

-"I am going to carry on with my university studies when I get back to my country."

-AmEng

Comment: @FelipeKunzler - I am glad my answer was helpful.  In general, we encourage people not to accept an answer right away - someone else may come along with an answer that addresses some nuance that I overlooked, or with disagreement.  In this case, I highly doubt anyone will say that my answer is wrong for United States English, but I would not be at all surprised to learn that English speakers from the rest of the world say it differently.

Comment: Do you find the phrasing using 'university' to be normal American usage? Given that the question is already in a non-American (European, I assume) phrasing, giving an American answer seems... off. I would expect something more like "I took a break from college/classes/school for six months." "I will (go back to)/(return to)/(resume) college/classes/school when I return to my country."

Comment: @Adam - Indeed, that is a great idea, I won't forget it next time!

Comment: @DCShannon - Yes, actually I'm living in Ireland, so I'm learning British English. However, since I've lived mostly American English in my entire life (Movies, TV Series, Articles, Internet, etc), my English now is kind of mixed, and I don't even care about it anymore actually, but I agree, It might not be good though.

Comment: @DCShannon On word choice:  I agree that  _"I took a break from college/school"_ would be more common than _"from university,"_ although I do hear people using the latter in that way.  If someone said they were taking a break from _classes_ I would assume they were a graduate student, and they were going to restrict themselves to research for the semester/quarter/whenever.  As for giving an "American" answer - for most questions, that's the only answer I know.  That's why I pointed out in both the answer and in a comment that people elsewhere might answer the question differently.